# how to uppercase each letter in dart?

Tags: dart, flutter

I tried this code but the result is just uppercase first letter (not each letter)

```
String ucwords(String input) {
    if (input == null) {
      throw new ArgumentError("string: $input");
    }
    if (input.length == 0) {
      return input;
    }
    return input[0].toUpperCase() + input.substring(1);
}
```

Comment: Have you ever try to understand what those words and symbols mean?

Comment: Try `input.toUpperCase()` instead of `input[0].toUpperCase() + input.substring(1)`

Comment: how if I want to uppercase of each character of letters?

Comment: @Ashta is your question solved? You have not marked an accepted answer so if the problem is still unclear please let us know how we can help

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you read the documentation for [`toUpperCase()`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/String/toUpperCase.html). It gives an example of exactly what you want to do.

Your code should read:

```
return input.toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, i didn't understand you question completely, but if you want to put each letter in Uppercase, this means all in Uppercase, well you can just use .toUpperCase() like this:

```
//This will print 'LIKE THIS'
print('like this'.toUpperCase());
```

But if you want to put an specific letter in UpperCase, you can just use the Text_Tools package:

https://pub.dev/packages/text_tools

Example

```
//This will put the letter in position 2 in UpperCase, will print 'liKe this'
print(TextTools.toUppercaseAnyLetter(text: 'like this', position: 2));

If this be of any help
```